# How to upload files to anonfiles with powershell

Tags: powershell, file-upload, upload

So i'm kinda new to powershell and want to make a simple script that will upload the chosen file to anonyfiles. The thing i'm having problems with is uploading to the api i have managed to upload it through cmd but now i'm hoping i can do it through powershell.

The command i used to upload the files through cmd is:

```
curl -F "file=@C:\Eclips-Terminal\Websites.csv" https://api.anonfiles.com/upload
```

To re-state it:

- Upload file to anonfiles (https://anonfiles.com/)
- If possible filter the output to only have the short url.

URLS:

- https://anonfiles.com/docs/api (API-Details)
- https://anonfiles.com (Website)

all help is welcome.

Comment: After some more testing it also doesnt want to run from a batch script maby some of you have more luck but for me it wont work.

Comment: Have you tried Copy-Item ?

Comment: no, not yet i will look into it.

Comment: @WalterMitty How would that work tho? All i can see is that you could copy the file but how would that upload it to the api?

Comment: OK, I misunderstood what you are trying to do.  There are some articles on the web about using cURL in powershell.

Comment: I'm still reading threw all of those aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell `curl` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`.

```
get-alias curl

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                   
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                   
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

You can still run any executable in powershell that you can run in cmd, just specify the executable.

```
curl.exe -F "file=@C:\Eclips-Terminal\Websites.csv" https://api.anonfiles.com/upload?token=<YOUR API KEY>
```

You will notice text in red, that's not an error but rather the way curl.exe writes it's progress to stderr stream which in powershell shows up in red. I have no doubt there is a switch/parameter you can use on curl.exe to omit this progress output but a simple way is to pipe stderr to `$null`.

```
curl.exe -F "file=@C:\Eclips-Terminal\Websites.csv" https://api.anonfiles.com/upload?token=<YOUR API KEY> 2>$null
```

Finally, if you capture the remaining output to a variable then you can extract your short url from it.

```
$output = curl.exe -F "file=@C:\Eclips-Terminal\Websites.csv" https://api.anonfiles.com/upload?token=<YOUR API KEY> 2>$null

($output | ConvertFrom-Json).data.file.url.short
```

Comment: Thanks very much also the cmd command did work fine and i could even download the file without a key. That most likely has to do with you not needing a account to use anonfiles.

Comment: I see. I'll update the post, thank you. Did the rest handle your expectations?